# React axios request return indext.html

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have added the proxy for the axios in package.json in my React app and tested by yarn start. It run as expected, but when I used serve to build and deploy on my computer, the request return me an index.html file. Is there anybody met the same problem.
proxy code:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080/",
```

axios request:

```
await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/cs122b_backend/api/movieList').then(
            response => {
                console.log("receive")
                this.setState({movieList: response.data});
                return response.data;
            }, error => {
                console.log(error)
                return error;
            }
        )
```

return result:

[image]

What confused me most is that the status code is 200 instead of 404.
Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Plz share the API code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score -1):

From the looks of it you are serving an html file.

Comment: this should be a comment to the question, not an answer